StringValues.Contains() always returns false
I'm trying to check if an Accept header includes a MIME type like this:
public static bool AcceptsView(this HttpRequest request) => request.Headers.Accept.Contains("text/html");

However even when the Accept header is Accept: text/html, text/plain, application/json it returns false. What am I doing wrong?

Did you debug and see what Accept actually is? I suppose it's a single-element collection with "Accept: text/html, text/plain, application/json". However your code checks for a three-element-collection with the values "text/html", "text/plain" and "application/json".

Is a list and not a string. Try to do ...Accept.Contains(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"))

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Yes, I debugged and the value is "text/html, text/plain, application/json", that's why I'm confused. Shouldn't it be an array of values containing the MIME types?

@DA I get this error: "CS1929 'StringValues' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'MemoryExtensions.Contains(ReadOnlySpan, MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue)' requires a receiver of type 'System.ReadOnlySpan<System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue>"

I think it is an array, however the debugger shows you the string-representation for it which is "Accept: text/html, text/plain, application/json". Anyway, you should just use request.Headers.Accept.Any(x => x.ToString() == "text/html");

I already tried that and there's no difference

Which HttpRequest class are we talking about? There is one inside the System.Web, there is another inside the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http namespace, etc..

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, ControllerBase.Request

The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest defines a property called Headers which is an IHeaderDictionary. This interface defines an Accept property which is a StringValues. This type basically a string collection which implements a lots of interfaces, like IEnumerable<string>.
Whenever you call Contains on the Accept that checks whether the provided string is present in the collection. In your case this property contains a single element. Not one element per acceptable mime type.
So, you have a collection with a single element text/html, text/plain, application/json and you are checking whether it has an element with text/html. That's the reason why it always returns false.
Option 1
So, you should check whether is there any item inside the StringValues collection which contains the provided string:
request.Headers.Accept.Any(x => x.Contains("text/html"))

Option 2
Another way to perform this check is to use the GetTypedHeaders. This will return a RequestHeaders instance. Its Accept property is not a StringValues rather a IList<MediaTypeHeaderValue>. So, here you have one MediaTypeHeaderValue per acceptable mime type.
The MediaTypeHeaderValue has a property called MediaType. Its type is a StringSegment which does have a Value property.
request.GetTypedHeaders().Accept.Any(x => x.MediaType.Value == "text/html")

You can also avoid hard coding text/html. The System.Net.Mime namespaces defines several classes like MediaTypeNames or MediaTypeNames.Text. The latter one has a constant called Html which contains the text/html
request.GetTypedHeaders().Accept.Any(x => x.MediaType == MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)

